# absolute position and margin 0 auto

Tags: css, positioning, absolute

I can't seem to figure out how to get the text to be positioned in the center of the wrapper. I have a responsive slideshow that I want text of top of and centered.

```css
ul.bjqs {
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:none;
}
.slideshow-tageline {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 1140px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:99;
    color: #fff;
    font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 125%;
    text-shadow: 2px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.tagline-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1140px;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-fade">
    <ul class="bjqs">
      <li> <div class="tagline-wrapper"><span class="slideshow-tageline">Every Moment Matters</span></div><img src="/includes/img/homepage/slider_images/slider_1.jpg"></li>
      <li> <div class="tagline-wrapper"><span class="slideshow-tageline">Every Moment Matters</span></div><img src="/includes/img/homepage/slider_images/slider_2.jpg" ></li>
      <li> <div class="tagline-wrapper"><span class="slideshow-tageline">Every Moment Matters</span></div><img src="/includes/img/homepage/slider_images/slider_3.jpg"></li>
      <li> <div class="tagline-wrapper"><span class="slideshow-tageline">Every Moment Matters</span></div><img src="/includes/img/homepage/slider_images/slider_4.jpg"></li>
      <li> <div class="tagline-wrapper"><span class="slideshow-tageline">Every Moment Matters</span></div><img src="/includes/img/homepage/slider_images/slider_5.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot use the auto-margin 'hack' on absolutely-positioned elements. The best you can hope for is to specify a size and then using negative 50% margins.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what your desired effect is. Regardless - what you could do instead of using absolute position, is position it relative to the parent this way it has the width of the parent, and you can center it with `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 3):

To center an element in position absolute you can do :

```
.myElement{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);    
}
```

You can do the same with top and translateY to center vertically.
Example : http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/zxQQXy

Edit: If you want to center both horizontally and vertically, you need to use transform: translate(-50%, -50%) because, I don't know why, they seem to override each other.